# Symfony 2.1+ encodes hash/pound "#" in routes

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm in the process of upgrading from Symfony 2.0 to 2.3. We have routes with hashes defined since we have a single page app.

A route configured via annotations:

```
/**
 * @Route("/app#orders/{id}", name="app_order")
 */
```

We use Twig to generate emails and use these routes within the Twig templates:

```
<a href="{{ url('app_order', { 'id': '123' }) }}">View order</a>
```

Before upgrading, this worked fine. After the upgrade, the `#` gets encoded to `%23` but the slashes remain intact. This of course generates an invalid URL in the email.

Why are only the hashes encoding and not the slashes? It should be all or nothing. What options do I have here other than doing a string replace?

Things I've already tried doing which don't help:

- Setting autoescape to false `{% autoescape false %}`
- Using raw `{{ url(...)|raw }}`
- Using raw and autoescape=false in conjunction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the [`UrlGenerator`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerator.php#L60) code, you can see, the hashtag is not decoded after `rawurlencode`.
The escaping of the hashtag was added in commit [6039569](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/603956979c5e413bd96fca1cb6ed38bdf185e321#src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerator.php).

As a workaround you could extend the `UrlGenerator` class and replace the `$decodedChars` array with hashtag included. Then tell Symfony to use your generator class:

```
parameters:
    router.options.generator_base_class: Acme\MyBundle\Routing\HashtagDecodedUrlGenerator
```

Comment: Good find. So sounds like it's less a Twig concern and more of a Symfony one.

Comment: I'm confused, which version you have used. Since this commit was already in the first release of symfony (v2.0.0).

Comment: We're on 2.0.21 and the hashes are definitely not being encoded there.

Comment: Ok. Compare the file at [2.0.21](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.0.21/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerator.php#L132) where only a part of the url (I think tokens means the {fields} in the url) gets encoded and at [2.3.4](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.3.4/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerator.php#L192) where whole url gets encoded. The change was in commit [3466896](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/3466896#L0R172). Maybe the posted workaround helpful?

Comment: Minor correction to your solution. It's actually the `generator_base_class` that needs to be overridden.